# Copy from Docker to the host

Tags: virtualbox, docker, file-copy, container

I'm newbie in docker world. I have a docker inside a Virtualbox image, and I want to copy files to the host. I tried as it is written here, and on many sites:
https://linuxhandbook.com/cp-command/

```
me@me-VirtualBox:~$ sudo docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
5c779efe4122   datasetdocker   "/a/local/dir:/user…"   9 minutes ago    Created                              distracted_knuth
d18ea89cd3d3   datasetdocker   "/bin/sh -c /bin/bash"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes                        zealous_taussig


me@me-VirtualBox:~$ sudo docker ps $d18ea89cd3d3
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
d18ea89cd3d3   datasetdocker   "/bin/sh -c /bin/bash"   33 minutes ago   Up 33 minutes             zealous_taussig


me@me-VirtualBox:~$ sudo docker cp d18ea89cd3d3:~/dataset /home/Documents
Error: No such container:path: d18ea89cd3d3:~/dataset
```

And inside the container:

```
user@d18ea89cd3d3:~$ ls
dataset
```

What did I miss here? How can I just copy a directory to my host os?

Comment: Does `sudo docker cp d18ea89cd3d3:/home/user/dataset /home/Documents` solve the problem?

Comment: The problem is most likely the ~

Comment: Just had a quick look at the `bash` docs: tilde expansion works when you begin a word with the tilde character, where a word is defined as a whitespace separated sequence of characters. So the `docker` command is receiving a literal tilde character in its source path.

Comment: @Haxiel It runs without problem, but actually didn't copied the dataset

Comment: @Haxiel even if it could expand, it would expand it incorrectly because it would use the host home not the docker container home

Comment: @AlmaKorte it did Not run without a problem. There's an error listen in your question.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I mean I've tried what Haxiel mentioned before, and it runs without errors, it's running for seconds but there is no copied file on the host.

Comment: @AlmaKorte It should be created as `/home/Documents/dataset`. If it is not, can you please add the working version of the command, and the output of `ls -l /home/user/dataset/` inside the container?

Comment: Just to be clear can you confirm there is no confusion here between the "docker host" (the virtual machine) and the virtual machine host (your laptop?). The docker cp command does not transfer files out of the vm onto your laptop.